# Is it possible to use custom images for UML items in plantUML?

Tags: plantuml

PlantUML is very powerful when you would like to create standard UML diagrams.

But I currently think about using PlantUML to document EIP routes (like the routes on these images: https://www.google.de/search?q=camel+route&safe=off&source=lnms&tbm=isch).

This would be pretty easy if you could specify another image instead of normal boxes for a class. Something like an SVG or WMF image or a shape script as in Sparx Enterprise Architect.

The only custom images I found in the documentation where those tiny sprites...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From the [PlantUML's Language Specification](https://plantuml.com/creole#f42f1366d9ab93bb)

> ### Legacy HTML
>
> You can mix Creole with the following HTML tags:
>
> ...
>
> - `<img:file>` : the file must be accessible by the filesystem
> - `<img:http://plantuml.com/logo3.png>` : the URL must be available from the Internet

It appears that it shouldn't be a problem. There is also a [PlantUML Word Plug-in](http://plantuml.com/word.html), that would possibly enable you to paste images over the default ones otherwise.

The following PlantUML code renders a simple diagram - the referenced images have to be in the proper location...

```
object "inbound message" as m1
object "XML Splitter" as s1

m1 : <img:MessageIcon.gif>
s1 : <img:SplitterIcon.gif>
m2 : <img:MessageIcon.gif>

m1 -> s1
s1 -> m2
```

[image]

Comment: that sounds like a solution which could work... can you come up with a working example which contains two elements linked together?

Comment: Images can be changed in size by using `{scale}` for instance: ```<img:http://plantuml.com/logo3.png{scale=0.5}>```

Answer (score 7):

[plantuml-icon-font-sprites](https://github.com/tupadr3/plantuml-icon-font-sprites) allows using font-awesome icons within plantuml. It's awesome!

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a diagram include `allow_mixing` at the top of the code.

Comment: Then it doesn't work. PlantUML documentation isn't as easy to navigate.