# Receate The Azure Scaleable Web App Diagram In UML

Tags: azure, uml, plantuml

Is it possible to recreate that Azure Scaleable Web App diagram [image: Azure Scaleable Web App diagram] using PlantUML?

If not, what would be a more appropriate way of doing it? Is the source that created the png available on GitHub?

Comment: While a general answer would be (to a degree) "Yes", your question is very broad. Is it possible to create a working code that will duplicate the function of Azure in UML in general or Plant UML specifically - no (or to be more specific probably not). Is it possible to model functionalities of the system in UML - yes. In Plant UML - to a degree. I would say you should read more about software development in general as your question suggests you don't have a full understanding of the process itself and explaining it here is way to broad.

Comment: Could you show us the result of your tries to remodel the diagram in plantUML ? That would make it easier to point out the differences.

Comment: you can (see https://github.com/tupadr3/plantuml-icon-font-sprites/blob/master/examples/complex-example.png ) but what is the interest to use a UML drawing tool to make that picture ?

Answer (score 1):

The following PlantUML code does exactly what you ask, but is probably not what you want:

```
@startuml
demo : <img:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/app-service-web-app/images/scalable-web-app.png>
@enduml
```

If you want to use PlantUML without images, then the answer is no, you can't, because the diagram does not comply to the UML standard.

You could isolate the individual symbols in separate image files and then use UML-relationships like associations and dependencies to draw the arrows in PlantUML, but you would not get exactly [the diagram you referred to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/app-service-web-app/images/scalable-web-app.png). For more information about how to use image files and sprites in PlantUML, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364024/is-it-possible-to-use-custom-images-for-uml-items-in-plantuml).

Instead, you could use your favorite general drawing tool, like Visio or PowerPoint, try to draw as much as you can and copy/paste the elements you can't draw yourself from the Azure diagram into Visio/PowerPoint/Whatever.

Comment: I agree with you and UV ( everything can happen on S.O. ^^)